# Add a "Total" row ath the bottom of the CSV react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I want to add a new row with only the "Total" label and the respective value.

```
  const csvContent = Papa.unparse(
    items.map(({ value1, value2, value3}, i) => {
      let item = {
        Index: i + 1,
        Name: value1,
        Value2: value2,
        Value3: value3,
      };
      return item;
    })
  );
```

The table looks like this:

```
 Index | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 
    1  |  value |  ...   |  ....
    2  |   ...  |  value |  ....
    3  |   ...  |  ...   |  value
```

And I want it to be like this

```
 Index | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 
    1  |  value |  ...   |  ....
    2  |   ...  |  value |  ....
    3  |   ...  |  ...   |  value
    
    Total                     234234
```

*With an empty row between the last table row and the total row

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, have you tried using a simple for? so you know wich is the last element, and wich is the first one, so you can insert in the first collumn total, and in the last one the value. If you want to use the map function you should use a counter, to keep track of the position

Comment: I've tried it, and it works but if the array has a length of 1 it does not work, only shows the 'total' row

Comment: @lonutBalan000 add a simple condition, if (arr.length < 2) { ... } so you can set that even if the array has e length of 1 you set the total value at the second collumn anyway